# Custom command with arguments

Tags: command-line, server, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running ubuntu on WSL, and now I want to make my command to start up my php server(Nginx, mysql, php). Right now everytime I boot my pc I always run `sudo service nginx start`, `sudo service mysql start`, and the php.

I want to make my own custom command that when I run it, it will execute the starting services command. Until this point I know how to make custom command. But the problem is, I have 2 projects that need 2 different php version(One 7.1 and the other is 7.3). Can I make a command that accept arguments and run the service based on the arguments.

My expectation:

`customcommand 7.1` will start nginx, mysql, and php7.1-fpm services

`customcommand 7.3` will start nginx, mysql, and php7.3-fpm services

I know, I can just make different commands like `customcommand7.1` and `customcommand7.3`. But if I can just make 1 command, why not?

Sorry if my question is a dump question. and Thanks! :D

Comment: in your case, just use a `if` / `case` statement (and don't forgot to start it using `sudo`)

Comment: @damadam how do you if / case in bash file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it in file some like `function.sh` and run it like:
bash function.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

customcommand () {
    sudo service nginx start
    sudo service mysql start
    sudo service php$1-fpm start
    # ... use switch case
    echo "Run v$1"
}

# this command execute version 7.1
customcommand 7.1
```

if it work, put this in `.bashrc` if it `linux`, or `.bash_profile` in `mac`

Comment: Thanks dude it works!